# implement click event in base xaml and handle it in base class in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, inheritance, overriding

I am new to WPF. I am creating some sample classes in order to fast create the final project. I have `CustomControl1` as base class,`Generic` as base xaml and `wInherit` as derived xaml and class. My base window's xaml is here:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Palayeshgah">
<!--x:Class="Palayeshgah.CustomControl1">-->
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="btnClose" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ...
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

...

<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource btnClose}" Name="btnClose" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18" Height="21"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is my derived xaml:

```
<ns:CustomControl1 x:Class="Palayeshgah.PL.Base.wInherit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Palayeshgah"
    Title="Inheritance Sample" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Wheat" MouseEnter="CustomControl1_MouseEnter"/>
```

Here is my base class:

```
public class CustomControl1 : Window
```

And this is my derived class:

```
public partial class wInherit : CustomControl1
```

These codes are showing base design perfectly. But I should override click event for my button. If I add `Click="btnClose_Click"` to `btnClose` in base xaml, I should intrtoduce a class in `Generic.xaml`. Just like below:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Palayeshgah"
x:Class="Palayeshgah.CustomControl1">
```

Then I receive an error as:

`Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Palayeshgah.CustomControl1'; another partial declaration of this type exists`.

I add `partial` to `CustomControl1` and then the error changed like below:

```
Partial declarations of 'Palayeshgah.CustomControl1' must not specify different base classes
```

I hang in here.

I didn't forget about `btnClose_Click`. Here is click event in base class:

```
protected virtual void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

You may ask Why I am separating base xaml from base class. The answer is I couldn't show base design with that approach.

Can anyone show me how to use inheritance for window and events in WPF with any approach please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't inherit CustomControl1 class. You create a usercontrol for Generic xaml and include it to your derived xaml.

Comment: I added new `UserControl` instead of `CustomControl1` and `Generic` and call that with `<local:BaseUserControl />`. `BaseUserControl` is new base user control. I docked that in new window and it works like a charm. Thank you for your brief clue.